# Audio Indexing: Generating time-aligned text tags from audio file

Tags: android, python, audio, speech-recognition

I need to pick out words & phrases from a large number of long audio files, with the end goal to generate a timestamp for the start and end point of each phrase.  The words and phrases are descriptions and light commentary about events that need to be time-tagged.   I've seen references to Google's GAudI, but it has disappeared ([link](https://www.lifewire.com/gaudi-google-audio-indexing-1616338)).  I've seen another solution ([Simple Audio Indexer](https://github.com/aalireza/SimpleAudioIndexer)) but it requires IBM Watson.  Perhaps its possible to use the Android speech-to-text processor?  Can anyone recommend some other solutions?  I prefer solutions with Python interfaces, but Java is possible too.   Thanks.

Comment: One option I'm looking at includes Forced Audio Alignment, such as this: https://github.com/readbeyond/aeneas.  Still investigating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spent quite a bit of time trying to get Android in-phone speech recognition to work in freeform mode, but its just not ready for primetime.  I and others havent found a way to turn off the beep every few seconds.

So instead I'm recording full audio files and running them through an indexer.  I found an interesting solution called [Aeneas](https://github.com/readbeyond/aeneas) but it depends on an old package called eSpeak and I had trouble getting it to install on OSX (eSpeak requires install privilege to directories that OSX has now locked down).

I next went ahead and tried [Simple Audio Indexer](https://github.com/aalireza/SimpleAudioIndexer) (SAI).  Setting up an account on IBM Watson BlueMix was painless and they give you 1000 minutes of free STT (Speech-to-text) time.  SAI is easy to install, simple to use and worked well.  I used `pydub` to convert my M4A/AAC files to WAV.  I did run into a problem requiring support from IBM and they responded in two hours with a run parameter that fixed my problem (needed to extend the inactivity_timeout beyond the default of 30 seconds).  Now it is working well.

Comment: aeneas dev here. Just a comment: aeneas can be installed via brew (which automatically pulls the dependencies) and there is an all-in-one installer for MacOS, please see: https://github.com/readbeyond/aeneas/blob/master/wiki/INSTALL.md#mac-os-x

Comment: BTW, I have a list of forced aligners on GitHub: https://github.com/pettarin/forced-alignment-tools